# Complex Search Request - Parameters are Record-specific

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, architecture

In my Rails 3.1 application I have a model that contains those attributes (all are integers):

- first_group_count
- second_group_count
- third_group_count
- second_group_max_age
- third_group_max_age

Basically, they refer to 3 groups of people (participants) whose age must be

- for `first_group`: greater than `second_group_max_age`
- for `second_group`: between `third_group_max_age` and `second_group_max_age`
- for `third_group`: between `0` and `third_group_max_age`

Now I need to perform a search on that model and what I have in request is an array of values like this: `[3, 5, 13, 16, 21]`

I need to find records that have 5 people in total (first_group_count + second_group_count + third_group_count = 5) and have room in their groups. (hope, you can get this)

**Example:**

Query: [3, 7, 14]

1. for records with `second_group_max_age=8` and `third_group_max_age=4` it should find records with:

   - first_group_count = 1
   - second_group_count = 1
   - third_group_count = 1
2. for records with `second_group_max_age=13` and `third_group_max_age=0` it should find records with:

   - first_group_count = 1
   - second_group_count = 2
   - third_group_count = 0

What would be the best solution to this problem? I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Ha! Help me out here. What does this mean "I need to find records that have 5 people in total (first_group_count + second_group_count + third_group_count = 5) and have room in their groups."

Comment: Really sorry! I tried my best to explain =) Maybe examples can help you. The point is that the _count attributes are dependent on max_age in each and every record. So you cannot tell in advance how to transform your query into number of people in each group. Does that help?

Comment: The main problem is how do I distribute the set of ages to groups depending on the record's specific rules.

Comment: Can you explain without programming jargon, what your app is trying to accomplish from a user's perspective? I'm still not getting it.

Comment: Ok, we have Vacation Packages. Every package is designed for X people. That X people is split between INFANTS, KIDS and ADULTS according to their ages. The maximum age to be an INFANT is stored in `third_group_max_age`. The maximum age to be a KID is `second_group_max_age`. Everyone older is an ADULT. When searching, you specify ages of people that are going like so [3, 5, 7, 14, 21]. How do you find the Packages that match your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. :)

It sounds like you just need to run these values `each` through a `case` clause like so :

```
def find_groups(x, y)
 # not sure if you want these dynamic or not..
 first_group_max_age = x
 second_group_max_age = y
 # start by making sure these are at a 0 count
 first_group = 0
 second_group = 0
 third_group = 0

 params[:values].each do |value|
   age = case value
     when > second_group_max_age then first_group += 1
     when > third_group_max_age && < second_group_max_age then second_group +=1
     when < third_group_max_age then third_group +=1
   end
 end
end

# now we have an idea about who many are in each group.. I'm still unsure about what your project is trying to accomplish from this point.. Enlighten me, and we can take this further..
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention! I really appreciate that. The problem is that `first_group_max_age` and `second_group_max_age` are specific for each record (every hotel, for instance, may have their own regulations) and stored in the database. So we need to make those calculations for each record in our table. (it is possible that the same values give you results where `first_group_count`, `second_group_count` e.t.c. are different)

Comment: No worries, just wrap the method up and pass those two dynamic vars into the method. Updated above.

Comment: Does this mean that in any case I have to first fetch **all** the records and then cycle them through?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you mention that different companies have different max age groups. So yes, then you would query through each company with this method. You mentioned that the only companies that should be returned are ones that would have 5 spots available. So make this method return `true` if that is the case. And then make your master call as so `Company.all.select{|company|company.find_groups(company.first_group_max_age, company.second_group_max_age)}`. Make sense?